# How would I use MVC4 WebAPI to chain controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

So my data model has something like this:   Author.Books
where a single Author can have multiple Books associated with it.

I can retrieve an Author with this route:  /api/Authors/4
... and I can get a list of all books like:  /api/Books, or a single book like  /api/Books/8

So how would I get all the books for a single Author?  something like:  /Authors/4/Books
I don't know what needs to happen to enable the "/Books" part of that example.  Do I modify the BooksController (and how)? Or the AuthorsController?  Or... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should seriously consider using the Powerful Odata translation capabilities of the web Api. It allows you to build rich queries directly in the querystring that are translated to a Linq expression. This is how I would solve your problem.

First, ensure that your book model has an AuthorId Property:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title{get; set;}
    public int AuthorId{get; set;}
}
```

Next, create a books controller and expose the Get method that returns an IQueryable:

```
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    public IQueryable<Books> Get()
    {
        var books = new List
        {
            new Book{Title = "Book 1", AuthorId = 1},
            new Book{Title = "Book 2", AuthorId = 2},
        };

        return books.AsQueryable();

    }
}
```

Finally, to query a book by a particular author your URI will look as such:

```
/books?$filter=AuthorId eq 2
```

Comment: While I am not opposed to this method.. it seems to violate the REST tenants..?

Comment: I would disagree. Rest is about resources and representations. We are still using the "/Books" resource to retrieve a representations of "Book" models. It's a common mis-perception that restful calls cant pass additional params. This call would violate restful idempotancy if it modified data on the server. All it does is give instructions to the restful "Get" about how to filter the data. Odata queries where designed to augment rest and are used by large restful api's such as netflix.

Comment: Thank you @jwanga.  I'd like to leave the question open for additional answers - perhaps someone will be able to address the question as it is.  If not I will be happy to mark your answer.